# FlaskForm with dynamically labelled StringField using dictionary

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

A simple flask form with a StringField looks like:

```
class SomeFormName(FlaskForm):
    value = StringField(label='Enter Value Here: ')
```

As an output from another function I have a dictionary that contains variables as keys and labels as values. These values will likely be different every time it is run. Is there anyway to make it so I can pass this dictionary to a FlaskForm, such that it creates the form with those fields dynamically? I know it doesn't work this way (I have tried) but, as an example of the type of functionality I am thinking of:

```
value_dict = {value1 :'Enter Value 1 Here: ', 
              value2 :'Enter Value 2 Here: ',
              value3 :'Enter Value 3 Here: ',}

class SomeFormName(FlaskForm, **dict):
    for value, label in dict.items(): 
        value = StringField(label=label)
```

Comment: If I understand, do you want to change the labels dynamically?

Comment: Add fields and change labels dynamically would be the closest idea, I suppose.  The length of the dictionary may range from 0 to half a dozen or so.

Comment: Did you check the answer I submit? Does it work?